# equality of two numbers which are odd powers of 2 and satisfy a certain condition

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $m,n$ be two positive integers and $2^{2n+1}-1\, | \, 2^{2m+1}-1$. Suppose $P_0$ be the largest prime number such that $P_0 \, | \, 2^{2m+1}-1$. If $P_0 \, | \, 2^{2n+1}-1$ then is the following equation true?
 $$2^{2n+1}-1 = 2^{2m+1}-1$$

Comment: Not necessarily.  Of course a consequence is that 2n+1 divides 2m+1.  It could happen that N is a Mersenne prime and that the larger number is N(N^2 +3N+3) and has N as its largest prime factor.  A look through the Cunningham tables should find a small counterexample if there are any.  Gerhard "Perhaps A Very Small Counterexample" Paseman, 2017.01.03.

Comment: There aren't that many Mersenne primes.  But there should be a positive probability that $2^p-1$ has a prime factor $> 2^{cp}$ for say $c = .8$, and also a positive and independent probability that $2^{3p}-1$ has no larger prime factor.  So there should be a positive albeit small density of counterexamples among exponents $3p$.  Likewise for $5p$, $7p$, etc. though rapidly decreasing.

Comment: ($p$ being a large prime.)

Comment: Fortunately you found an example involving a Mersenne prime and posted it just before I posted my comment.  It would be nice to know if similar examples existed using other bases. Or even which N have N^4 + 5(N^3 + 2N^2 + 2N +1) break into 4 or more times as many prime factors as N has.  Gerhard "Cell Phones Are Much Slower" Paseman, 2017.01.03.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm guessing, based on the fact that for each $\epsilon>0$
random $x$ has all prime factors are less than $x^\epsilon$ with
positive probability, but also has a prime factor greater than $x^{1-\epsilon}$
with positive probability.  But the first probability decays rapidly enough
($\exp$ of something like $\log(\epsilon) / \epsilon$) that the first
example with $2^p-1 \mid 2^{5p}-1$ might be quite large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  $(2n+1,2m+1) = (17,51)$ is a counterexample because
$$
2^{51} - 1 = 7 \cdot 103 \cdot 2143 \cdot 11119 \cdot 131071
$$
and $131071 = 2^{17}-1$ is prime.  The only other counterexample with $m \leq 100$ is $(2n+1,2m+1) = (37,111)$ with $P_0 = (2^{37}-1)/223 = 616318177$.

P.S. **gp** code:

```
forstep(k=3,200,2,if(!isprime(k),f=factor(2^k-1)[,1]; r = znorder(Mod(2,f[#f])); if(r<k, print([r,k]))))
```

P.P.S. The condition $2^{2n+1} - 1 \mid 2^{2m+1} - 1$ is equivalent to
$2n+1 \mid 2m+1$.

Comment: That was pretty fast!

Comment: I was a minute too slow, I've just found this example :P

Comment: The equivalent condition is inherited from cyclotomic polynomials.

Comment: No need for cyclotomic polynomials. 
In general, for any integers $b,s>1$ and $r,r'\geq 0$ we have
$r \equiv r' \bmod s \Rightarrow b^r - 1 \equiv b^{r'} - 1 \bmod b^s - 1$
(using $b^s \equiv 1$).  If $r'$ is the least nonnegative residue of
$r \bmod s$, then $b^{r'} - 1 < b^s - 1$, so $b^r-1$ is a multiple of $b^s-1$
**iff** $r$ is a multiple of $s$.

Comment: Curiously, the pair $(17,51)$ is also a counterexample to a related problem: the largest prime factor of $2^{51}+1$ divides $2^{17}+1$.  This is not the case for $(37,111)$.