# equality of two numbers which are in $4k+2$-form powers of 2 and satisfy a certain condition

Tags: nt.number-theory

This question is similar to [this  one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258702/equality-of-two-numbers-which-are-odd-powers-of-2-and-satisfy-a-certain-conditio).

Let $m,n$ be two positive integers and $2^{4n+2}+1\, | \, 2^{4m+2}+1$. Suppose $P_0$ be the largest prime number such that $P_0 \, | \, 2^{4m+2}+1$. If $P_0 \, | \, 2^{4n+2}+1$ then is the following equation true?
 $$2^{4n+2}+1 = 2^{4m+2}+1$$

Comment: I suspect the answer is "yes"; even for the pair $(2^n+1,2^m+1)$ provided $m>3$.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan The largest prime factor of $2^{51}+1$ is $43691$, which divides $2^{17}+1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Oh, you're right  thanks. I was meaning to write $(2^{2n}+1,2^{2m}+1)$. I Hope this is correct.

Comment: @T. Amdeberhan: That's not right either -- $(n,m)=(58,174)$.